# Making a PyInstaller exe do both command-line and windowed

Tags: python, windows, command-line, pyinstaller

I am writing a Python program that can be used both on the command-line, and as an interactive window. (Is that a bad idea?) If command-line arguments are supplied, it executes a task, then prints "success" or "failure". Otherwise, it launches an interactive window.

PyInstaller doesn't seem to be built to support this. I have two non-optimal options:

1. Use --console mode: The command-line works great, but if I double-click the exe to show the interactive window, it also shows a console window that I don't want
2. Use --noconsole mode: There's no console popup, but no output shows when using the command-line.

It seems I either need a way to not pop-up the console in --console mode, or to show print output in --noconsole mode. If neither of those options work, I may need to make a separate command-line version of the program.

Any advice?

Comment: did you open a feature request for this so that I can also add my +1 to it?

Comment: I opened a feature request here https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6244

Answer (score 11):

This is not a perfect solution, but this workaround did the job for me:

Build gui app in --noconsole --one file mode like this:

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile hello.py
```

When you double click on the app from windows it will launch normally (without the console).

Now to see the output, navigate to the executable from the command line and type:

```
hello.exe | more
```

The "| more" should send the print statements to the console.

Comment: | findstr "^" works too, and doesn't block like more

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with Windows (not PyInstaller), which requires the subsystem to be specified as either `CONSOLE` or `WINDOWS` at compilation-time.

- https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6244#issuecomment-927131015

The recommended solution is to split your app (eg `hello`) into two distinct versions:

1. `hellow.exe` for the GUI version (windowed) and
2. `hello.exe` for the CLI version (console)

In theory, you could also add a wrapper `.exe` that switches between the two actual binaries above, depending on how it's called..

Comment: that theory won't work, since the calling program is the one that allocates the console, and chooses to block/not block based on the subsystem.   there's no way to trick powershell into waiting for the results... just have to have 2 exe's